# Ace value in a low straight

Tags: texas-hold-em

I play Hold'em with some guys from work and we had an interesting ruling I have a question about. The community cards are A,2,3,4,5 not suited.  There are two players.  Player one is holding A,8 and player 2 is holding 2,10.  The ruling that i contested was that player 1 wins because the A beats the 2.  This doesn't seem like the correct ruling imo.  Isn't the A lower than the 2 in a 5 high straight?  I'm very curious because this started an argument with me trying to explain this which almost led to a physical confrontation.  I'd like to know I was at least right.  :P

Answer (score 2):

If you play Holdem and the community cards read A2345, than neither A8 nor T2 wins. Its a push. Both players make the same straight, 5-high. It doesn’t matter who holds what card in the holecards, unless one of you had a 6 in the hand that supercedes the “common straight”.

On a side note, when Ace is used in the 5-high street, it’s nokination is 1 and is actually lower than 2. That is, if it was important at all, which is not in this case.